# Powershell is returning exit code too quickly

Tags: powershell

I have a script to uninstall McAfee antivirus and the agent associated with it.

The issue i'm having is that the script provides an exit code too early and doesn't continue through. If I run the script multiple times I get the desired result, but as we're trying to push it out via PDQ remotely, we need it to run through the script and only provide an exit code at the end of the script.

I'm a powershell novice so there's probably a much better and easier way to write this script but any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/x {CE15D1B6-19B6-4D4D-8F43-CF5D2C3356FF} REMOVE=ALL REBOOT=R /q"; Write-Host "Uninstalling McAfee VirusScan Enterprise 8.8..."

$version = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
Write-Host "Detected OS as $version"

if ($version -like '*Windows 7*')
{
    Write-Host "Uninstalling McAfee Agent..."

    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\Common Framework\frminst.exe" -ArgumentList "/forceuninstall"
}

elseif ($version -like '*Windows 10*')
{
    Write-Host "Unmanaging McAfee Agent for Uninstall Process.."

    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\maconfig.exe" -ArgumentList "/provision /unmanaged"; 

    Write-Host "Uninstalling McAfee Agent..."

    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\McAfee\Agent\x86\frminst.exe" -ArgumentList "/forceuninstall"
}

else
{
    exit
}
```

Comment: have you tried the `-Wait` parameter yet? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Start-Process reports a return code as soon as it starts the process indicating whether it was successful or not. Either use -wait to force the script to wait until it finishes or capture the output and proceed based on what the returnvalue is. See the docs for [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)